# Heroku "We're sorry, but something went wrong" after Postgres migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, crash, migration

I recently did Heroku's requested database migration from a "shared database" to Postgres. I followed Heroku's directions carefully, and it all went fine until the last step: removing the old shared database. At that point, my app went down with the "something went wrong" message, and it's been down ever since (going on two weeks now).

Note that the app was still working after the step in which I switched to the new database, and according to "heroku config", it is using the new database. It shouldn't care about the old one disappearing. The logs say nothing other than 500 errors.

I submitted an urgent support request to Heroku, but they were not helpful. They just said that my data is still there but, "Your application isn't logging so it's not clear why this is happening but it doesn't appear to be due to the migration." That was a week ago, so it's not looking like they're going to do anything more.

I agree that the problem shouldn't be due to the migration, but given that I've made no changes to the app except the migration, and that it died exactly when I removed the old database, I don't see what else it could be.

My app is probably pretty old at this point (Rails 3.0.3), so my only thought now is to update everything to the latest versions and redeploy. The app is used to record merit badges and rank advancements for our local Boy Scout troop, so I really need to get it running again. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I now have a theory. As hgmnz says, the fact that the app went down exactly when I removed the old database strongly implies that it was using that database. How can that be, when I did all the proper migration steps, and "heroku config" says I'm using the new database? How about this: my app is so old that it isn't using the stack (bamboo) in the way that Heroku support thinks it is. I'm hoping that upgrading to the latest infrastructure and redeploying will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct would to db:pull the heroku hosted database. (make a copy).

Then try to start your app locally.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has fixed the problem. My hypothesis was correct: my app was so old that the migration procedure did not actually update it to use the new database. They say that they'll be applying the fix to their other old apps now.

Answer (score 0):

If the app started failing the moment you removed the shared database, it means that your app was still connected to this database and was never connecting to the new one. It sounds to me like you did not run `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color of new database> --app <your-app>`. Can you try that?

Edit:

Based on the further info provided in your comments, it's possible that this is a potential issue in the aspen and bamboo stacks (that only affect a few customers). The thing to try now is a new deploy. Try making a trivial change - maybe a newline in your project README - and deploy the app again. This will force a slug recompile that will write out a new database.yml using the correct DB.

Even better would be to migrate to the cedar stack though

Comment: I did do that. It's part of the migration instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres). Also, "heroku config" says that I'm using the new database. But, I just tried it again to make sure. No good.